# CSS - Background Position with background clip text using css variables as percentage

Tags: css, css-variables

i'm tryng to clip a linear gradient on text and set the background position with a css variable.
It's not work with percentage but only if i set a px value.

as you can see, if you try to change the px value in % it doesn't work.

```css
:root{
  --percent : 50px;
}

body{
  background-color: #aeaeae;
}

.hello{
  font-size: 10rem;
  background: linear-gradient(
    #aaeeff, #ddddff
  ) no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-position-y: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">HELLO</div>
```

i want to do that whitout js

thanks

Comment: This doesn’t have anything to do with using CSS variables directly, but with percentages for background-position. Those are based on the actual image dimensions - which you don’t have here, because you have no image in the first place. I had no luck with trying to specify a background-size either here.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
:root {
--percent : calc(10rem/2);
}

body{
  background-color: #aeaeae;
}

.hello{
  font-size: 10rem;
  background: linear-gradient(
    #aaeeff, #ddddff
  ) no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-position-y: var(--percent);
}
```

Comment: This is great! but to do that you need to know. the font size. If you image that --percent variable is calculate via javascript. you need to get in some way the font size. or hardcode it. (not so elegant)